# If $V$ is an irreducible representation then is $S(V\otimes V)$?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $V$ be an irreducible $FG$-module of dimension $2$. Is $S(V\otimes V)$ irreducible? Why?

$G$ is a finite group.
$F$ is a field, its order is unspecified.

$S(V\otimes V)=\{x \in V\otimes V : xT=x\}$

$A(V\otimes V)=\{x \in V\otimes V : xT=-x\}$

Comment: Who are $G$ and $FG$? Since $V$ is unrelated to them I would bet that "you can't tell".

Comment: Presumably $G$ is a finite group, $F$ a field, and $FG$ the group algebra. Standard way of describing a representation. Also I fixed a typo: the initial '$G$' should have been '$V$.'

Comment: OP, what do you mean by *symmetric* tensor product? Are you talking about the symmetric square ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$, i.e. $V\otimes V$ *quotiented by the subspace generated by* $a\otimes b-b\otimes a$? If that is what you're talking about, then you should say so, and writing $V\otimes V$ is misleading (since $V\otimes V$ is *not* the symmetric square). If you are simply talking about $V\otimes V$ (which is what you have written), do not write "symmetric," because that has a specific meaning in the context of tensor products.

Comment: So you *are* talking about $S(V\otimes V)$ right? Though you edited in the definition of $S(V\otimes V)$ and $A(V\otimes V)$ in, if you read your question you will see that you have it still referring to $V\otimes V$ (rather than $S(V\otimes V)$) in two places. (Also, is $T$ the map $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$, and are you applying morphisms from the right?)

Comment: I will have to ask my lecturer to clarify

Comment: I believe that should be a little clearer now, hopefully. Part of my problem is just trying to understand all these terms.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no reason for this to be true, e.g. there exist groups which only have irreducible representations of dimension at most $2$, but if $\dim V = 2$ then $\dim S^2(V) = 3$, so it can't be irreducible. The smallest such group is $S_3$.

In fact $S^2(V)$ frequently has a trivial direct summand; this happens iff $V$ admits a $G$-invariant symmetric bilinear form iff $V$ is the complexification of a real $G$-representation (see [Frobenius-Schur indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator)).

Comment: So, by $S^2(V)$, do you mean $S(V\otimes V)$?

Comment: Yes. The notation you're using is not standard.

Comment: Thank you, that's somewhat clearer now